# SQL Server group by but select 'top' date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL server like so (Note the ID field is not unique):

```
-----------------------------------
| ID | IsAdamBrown | DateComplete |
| 1  |     TRUE    | 2017-01-01   |
| 1  |     TRUE    | 2017-01-03   |
-----------------------------------
```

I'd like to select one row for all the unique IDs in the table and the ***most recent*** 'DateComplete' for that ID.

My desired output in this case would be:

```
-----------------------------------
| ID | IsAdamBrown | DateComplete |
| 1  |     TRUE    | 2017-01-03   |
-----------------------------------
```

I've tried:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT DateComplete, ID, IsAdamBrown 
  FROM thisTable
  WHERE IsAdamBrown IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY DateComplete, ID, IsAdamBrown
  ORDER BY DateComplete DESC
```

Unfortunately I still get the two date rows back. In MySQL I would group by just the first two rows and the `ORDER BY` would make sure the DateComplete was the most recent. SQL servers requirement that the `SELECT` fields match the `GROUP BY` makes this impossible.

***How can I get a single row back for each ID with the most recent DateComplete?***

Comment: By "Most Recent" date, do you mean the date closest to today, or the date most recently entered into the database? If its the former, you can use `Max(DateComplete)`. For the latter, I'm not sure there's enough information in the tables you've presented to get it

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix I mean the date closest to today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       isadambrown, 
       Max(datecomplete) AS DateComplete 
FROM   thistable 
GROUP  BY id, 
          isadambrown 
ORDER  BY Max(datecomplete) DESC
```

Comment: Why is group by IsAdamBrown? If ID is same but IsAdamBrown is not same, What result is correct?

Comment: If you wanted to group by isadambrown then @arulkumar answer is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can get by `GROUP BY` with `MAX()` of `DateComplete`

```
  SELECT ID, IsAdamBrown, MAX(DateComplete) AS DateComplete
  FROM thisTable
  WHERE IsAdamBrown IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ID, IsAdamBrown
  ORDER BY MAX(DateComplete) DESC
```

Comment: OP says "I'd like to select one row for all the unique IDs in the table and the most recent 'DateComplete' for that ID".What if there's a record with ID 1 and IsAdamBrown False??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for grouping according to `ID` and a subquery to get the only first record with recent iscomplete. This will first sort your data according to id and recent iscomplete and then the first result for all the unique IDs

```
SELECT X.ID, X.IsAdamBrown, X.DateComplete 
FROM ( SELECT ID, IsAdamBrown, DateComplete,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateComplete DESC) RN
       FROM thisTable
       WHERE IsAdamBrown IS NOT NULL    ) X
WHERE X.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using LIMIT

```
  SELECT ID, IsAdamBrown, DateComplete
  FROM thisTable
  WHERE IsAdamBrown IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ID, IsAdamBrown
  ORDER BY DateComplete LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1`?, question tagged with `SQL-Server`

Comment: Also, there will be more than one ID in the table that should be returned by this query. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT ID, IsAdamBrown, DateComplete
  FROM thisTable a
  WHERE DateComplete IN 
(
SELECT MAX(DateComplete) FROM thisTable b WHERE a.ID = b.ID GROUP BY b.ID
) ORDER BY DateComplete DESC
```